# undefined method `new' for Fixnum:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

```
    class Fixnum
      def repeat
        for i in 1..self.to_i
          yield
        end
      end
    end

    z = Fixnum.new 4
```

The program above is giving `undefined method new for Fixnum:Class (NoMethodError)`. Why so? I just tried using it in another class and it works.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't `repeat` a strange name for a method that will yield different values at each iteration and not repeat the same? Also you are basically reimplementing `Hash#each` (`(1..z).each { |x| ... }`).

Comment: BTW, `Fixnum#times` does the same thing! In addition, it yields numbers from `0` to `n-1`.

Comment: I believe the code was an example to understand how .each and methods like that work, not a method Vinisa was trying to create, and also, the method does what the name says, it repeats the block n times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me that the method and the error have no relation, why are you doing z = Fixnum.new 4?

The method should be used like:

```
class Fixnum
  def repeat
    for i in 1..self.to_i
      yield
    end
  end
end

5.repeat{puts "hi"}
#or maybe?
z = 3
z.repeat{puts "bye"}
```

Comment: oh okay. Actually I am new to ruby, and saw a similar call to class in different example so was trying. Thanks!